# Select Count(Id) in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to write a linq query to result in :

```
select Count(Id) from tbl1
```

because

```
tbl1.Select(q=>q.Id).Count()
```

doesn't translate to the result that I want

update :

it returns :

```
select count(*) from tbl1
```

Update after answer :

I tested the scenario with more than 21,000,000

[image: execution plan]

[image: record counts]

Comment: Does it return a different result?

Comment: Use `Where` instead of `Select`

Comment: Perhaps `tbl1.Count(x => x.Id != null)`

Comment: From a comment of the OP I take it that "select Count(Id) from tbl1"   is meant literally thus he wants count(id) not count(*)

Comment: yes , but no linq query can translate to that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to write a linq query to result in.

No. First thing is to understad what you need, for sample, in `T-SQL`, you can use:

- `COUNT(*)` will counts the rows in your table
- `COUNT(column)` will counts the entries in a column - ignoring null values.

If you need to count how many rows you have, just use

```
var total = tbl1.Count();
```

If you need to see how many entities you have where a specific column is not null, then use a filter overloads of `Count` method.

```
var total = tbl1.Count(x => x.Id != null);
```

No, it is not possible. There is not difference realted with performance using `Count(*)` or ´Count(Id)`, even more if your`Id` is the primary key.

I did an experiment with a table here with more than one million tuples. See the executioon plan of both queries. The first one is the `select count(*)` and second one is `select count(id)`. The `id` is the primary key (sorry the results are in portuguese-brazil):

[image]

Comment: So , I know the difference but i wanted to see if there is a way to have that query or not . it seems that is not possible

Comment: No, it is not possible. There is not difference realted with performance using `Count(*)` or ´Count(Id)`, mainly if your `Id` is the primary key.

Comment: what about the situation which Id is not primary key . Is there any performance using Count(*) or Count(Id) ?

Comment: @FelipeOriani As far as I'm aware from sql itself it is slower if you use count(*) instead of using count(primarykey). was so at least 5-10 years ago with mysql and the sql server back then

Comment: Guys, see my update. I did a experiment here with both queries in a table where there are more than one million of tuples. It would be nice if you @unosbaghaii do the same.

Comment: interesting then things seemingly changed from back then there good to know!

Comment: @Felipe Oriani . Yes they are the same . I have tested with 3 million records and the execution plans were the save . thanks

Answer (score 5):

Using `count(field)` in sql counts all non-null values. In linq, you can say:

```
tbl1.Where(q => q.Id != null).Count();
```

or simply:

```
tbl1.Count(q => q.Id != null);
```

Comment: @unosbaghaii Ah I think it was a bit unclear  with your definition. you don't want to count and have a problem with the null values but you just want to count the number of different id's

Comment: @unosbaghaii You should provide sample data and expected answer. It is really necessary in database related questions.

Comment: Have to add there normally count(id) and count(*) return the same result as id is normally the name for the primary key value of a table. Thus if it is not the same the table content and buildup is unexpected and that can lead to answers that are not complete or do not fullfill what you want to have.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to get

> select Count(Id) from tbl1

would be

```
tbl1.Where(q => q.Id != null).Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count();
```

The above `Where` is there to avoid `null` values. If you want them to also be counted, the `Where` needs to be eliminated and the `Select` adjusted to deal with `null` entries.

Additionally if you don't want to count just distinct values then the `Select` and `Distinct` parts can be disregarded.